# Angular Material Header

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How to allow duplicate header value in angular material.

I am having multiple header and here header value are same. It is giving error:-

**Duplicate column definition name provided**

Comment: Create demo or give sample code for better understanding

Comment: I am following this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vy5fvc?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts) . Here suppose all column name are same

Comment: @gsr I have tried to work out what you mean but in future it would be much easier if you could provide more detail of the actual problem you are having. Maybe even just changing the stackblitz to recreate the error would have helped a lot. I Hope my answer solves your issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[If you read the docs here, you will see the following:](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatColumnDef)

> @Input('matColumnDef') name: string
>
> **Unique** name for this column.

(emphasis mine)

I am assuming (as you didn't share any code) that the reason you are getting this error is because you have the same name listed more than once in the displayed columns array.

A way around this is to create new objects which contain the property/column name as well as a uniqueIdentifier for angular to use internally (in my example I have put these in an array called `columnObjects`)

The component then becomes

```
export class TableBasicExample {

    // displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
   dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;

   columnObjects = [
       { columnId: 'position', propertyName: 'position' },
       { columnId: 'name1', propertyName: 'name' },
       { columnId: 'name2', propertyName: 'name' },
       { columnId: 'weight', propertyName: 'weight' },
       { columnId: 'symbol', propertyName: 'symbol' }
   ];

   columnIds = this.columnObjects.map(c => c.columnId);
}
```

and can be used in the template like:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col.columnId" *ngFor="let col of columnObjects">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ col.propertyName }} </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[col.propertyName] }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnIds"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnIds;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Note how I am only passing `columnIds` to the internals of angular material. This is because these are unique.

[I have created a working example on stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vy5fvc-emfuxh?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Hope this is clear.

Answer (score 3):

For those who are facing this issue since the update to Angular 9 like Darren and don't want to move the nested table into a separate template, you can simply add an *ngIf to the nested table:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" *ngIf="element == expandedElement">
```

Update:
This **bug has been solved** with @angular/material Version 9.2.0

Comment: thanks a lot..I was looking everywhere for an answer

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who've ended up on this question due to upgrading to Angular 9 with nested tables like Darren, it looks like the solution is to move the nested table into a separate template:

```html
<table mat-table>
...

<!--Move the nested table out of the parent table and into a template, then reference it with a container-->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="nestedTable; context: { datasource: myRowsChildDatasource }"></ng-container>
...
</table>

<ng-template #nestedTable let-datasource="datasource">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="datasource">
  </table>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it was my mistake because I had 2 columns with the same name ( `matColumnDef="email"` in my case), so the  **matColumnDef** should be unique.